# Php reCaptcha not showing on server

Tags: php, recaptcha

I am a new PHP programmer. I am using reCaptcha for my website. It was showing normally earlier but does not show up now. The code is working on my localhost.

I have signed up for reCaptcha, entered my domain name and obtained the generated keys. After that, I downloaded the reccaptchalib.php and deployed it to my server.

Kindly help me as I don't know what to do next.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have signed up for this functionality then it would be best to ask the providers of the service for help as the problem could be quite numerous i.e. invalid key, location of key file incorrect etc

Comment: thanks for reply sir.First it was showing on my server but i have checked it a few days latter.now its not showing.

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting any PHP errors in the logs? Is it possible that you moved the reCaptcha library to a different path or moved the script?

I had a similar problem and it was caused by "cleaning up" and I moved the reCaptcha library into a subfolder.